# What's the best solution for creating a help page?

Tags: .net, documentation, sandcastle

I've seen a few posts about different solutions such as Sandcastle for documenting code. However, I'm wondering if there is a solution designed for non-developers. Would a solution such as Sandcastle, NDoc, or GhostDoc be best suited for the general user without a programming background?

At the same time I want to be able to eventually add some developer stuff in the far future once I start implementing developer tools into the site. Any suggestions on lite weight and easy to manage solutions for a help system? or is Sandcastle the way to go? It's a .net website similar to a wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandcastle, GhostDoc, etc are tools for developers that generate documentation for the source code. This documentation is for developers only, not the users of the final software solution.

For help files for end users you can use [Microsoft Help 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_2) or a full-blown authoring tool like [Flare](http://www.madcapsoftware.com/products/flare/overview.aspx).